# Showing uniform convergence of $f_n(x) = x+\frac{x^n}{n}$ and convergence of $f_n'$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I need to show that

$$f_n(x) = x+\frac{x^n}{n}$$

converges uniformly to a differentiable function in $[0,1]$, the sequence of derivatives $f_n'$ converges pointwise in $[0,1]$, but $f_n' \neq (\lim f_n)'$

First of all, I think the limit of $f_n(x)$ is $0$, so I tried to analyze

$$\left|x+\frac{x^n}{n}\right| = \left|\frac{nx+x^n}{n}\right|<^*\left|\frac{n}{n}\right|$$

*when $x\in [0,1]$

but that doesn't help

The sequence of derivatives is $1+x^{n-1}$ which we know converges pointwise, and $[\lim f_n]' = x' = 1$ so at least I showed that $f_n' \neq [\lim f_n]'$. What about the uniform convergence of $f_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $\;x\in[0,1]\;$ :

$$x+\frac{x^n}n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x+0=x=:f(x)$$

and the convergence is uniform because for *any* $\;x\in[0,1]\;$ :

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\frac{x^n}n\le\frac1n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$$

Clearly, for all $\;x\in[0,1]\;:\;\;f'(x)=1\;,\;\;f_n'(x)=1+x^{n-1}\;$ , yet when $\;x=1\;$ we have that

$$f_n'(1)=1+1^{n-1}=2\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\neq1$$

Comment: +1 In fact, the sequence $f_n'$ does not even converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Just observe that $\vert f_n(x)-x\vert =x^n/n \le 1/n$ so $f_n(x)\to x$ uniformly.

Answer (score 0):

if $f_n$ converges uniformly, then $\sup f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$

if you want to use the derivatives you have calculated then:

let $g_n = |f_n(x) - f(x)|$

Use the mean value theorem

for and $a,b \in [0,1]$ there is a $c \in (0,1)$ such that $g_n'(c) = \frac {g_n(b) - g_n(a)}{b-a}$

$\sup g(x) < g'(x)$

Now show that $n>N ,g'(x) = \epsilon$

but it is not really necessary.

I think you can demonstrate $\sup |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$ outright.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** for the uniform convergence if $(f_n)$ at $[0,1]$.

The pointwise limit is $x$ at $[0,1]$

and

$$\forall x\in[0,1]\; |f_n(x)-x|=|\frac{x^n}{n}|\leq\frac{1}{n}$$

You can conclude.